# Adding oncontextmenu with appendChild()

Tags: javascript

Hey is it possible to add a oncontextmenu to an element via JavaScript if you use appendChild???

I set my div like this:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'G';
d.className = 'Ouput';  
document.getElementById('E').appendChild(d);
```

But I'm wondering how i add:

`oncontextmenu="return false;"`

Can it be added to the Div properties before I append child or do I have to add it afterwards some how ?

Comment: Did you try putting it before... or after you append it?

Comment: I haven't done either - i don't understand how you would add a JS function to div ID `G` using this method in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the oncontextmenu before or after the div is added to the dom but use a function instead of a string.

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'G';
d.className = 'Ouput';
d.oncontextmenu = function(){return false};
document.getElementById('E').appendChild(d);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ZNvhD/